# Why would someone carry a traditional longbow instead of compound bow?

Tags: warfare, weapons

I have a community with great knowledge but limited resources so bows are preferenced over guns. Is there any reason why their warriors would carry "English" long bows instead of modern style compound bows? Mainly looking for tactical excuses.

Comment: There are a lot of discussions around "self bow vs composite bow" topic. The consensus seem to be that composite bows, while generally superior, are more sensitive to moisture.

Comment: since there are so many different types of each in existence, it is all down to personal preference... correction, the general's taste!

Comment: @Alexander: I think the OP means a COMPOUND bow - the high-tech ones with wheels & cables - rather than a Mongol-style composite bow.

Comment: @jamesqf I get those two confused constantly!

Comment: @jamesqf - hmm, if it's a modern tech compound bow, I am at real loss about its tactical disadvantages. Of course it has more points of failure than a simple bow, but M16s are getting jammed too.

Comment: Doesn't the "limited resources" part already answer the question? If they have the resources to make compound bows, they probably also have the resources to obtain guns.

Comment: `limited resources`. a compound bow contains plastics and metals, generally harder to get hold of than wood. Those little wheels will have to be accurately round, meaning you need machines to make accurately round plastic wheels - making those machines takes resources. And those wheels will run on some kind of very precisely machined (more machines!) bearing or bush, which will need to be lubricated (resources!) - and very clean (unreliable!). Or just cut a branch off a tree and shave it into a stave - with the "downside" being that warriors training with that bow get ridiculously strong.

Comment: What does "limited resources" mean here anyway? Limited types of materials, or limited amount of resources? Not having access to proper metals, ceramics, or plastics makes a compound bow a bad choice, but not having a good supply of high (high!) quality wood makes a longbow infeasible.

Comment: "Limited Resources" is a post apocalyptic situation resulting in a break down in trade and mineral extraction. The particular group in question are a "science" enclave, have maintained knowledge base and small scale machining capabilities.

Comment: Can you clarify `compound bows`? Is that 'modern compound' or 'historic compound (recurve)'? And does 'composite bow' fit in anywhere?

Comment: Modern Compound bow. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Compound Bows**

*Pros*

- Easier to use
- Average user can shoot further
- More accurate without practice
- Smaller & lighter

*Cons*

- Complex & slow construction
- Suffers wear & tear faster
- Suffers from the environment faster
- Requires laminate wood, fiberglass, or carbon fiber to take full advantage
- Though few consider it, the pullies can be jammed (think "mud")
- Though few consider it, natural wood arrows are often too soft for the power behind the bow.

**Longbows**

*Pros*

- Easy to manufacture
- Easy to maintain
- Effective without lamination/fiberglass/carbon fiber
- Highly effective with natural wood arrows
- Withstands weather well
- Has no moving parts to get gummed up

*Cons*

- Bulky
- Longer training curve
- Shorter range
- Less power

Comment: You missed pro for longbow- faster firing rate.

Comment: @pojo-guy, That's an interesting point.  The point of the compound is to reduce the pound-draw, which would imply a faster pull.  I've never used a compound.  I have used a long bow with a 75# draw.  My gut reaction is that the compound would be faster.  What do you think?

Comment: @JBH I'm a very much an amateur, but I have used both compound bows and longbows, and I would guess that for a trained user the longbow would be faster. The reason in my mind is the slump at the end of the draw for the composite, I think it makes you slow down to re-aim as the abrupt change in the draw strength seems likely to throw you off. Also I always thought the main goal of the compound is to allow for longer and easier aiming. Once you've drawn the bow fully there is essentially no power needed anymore.

Comment: Do you have sources for the ranges? Longbow targets were up to 400yards, but modern bows ranges are only 70m.

Comment: It's obviously not the same as war, but larp and reenactment are close - and having taken standard and recurve bows to larp I know that they do get muddy and dirty. Cleaning them is as simple as wiping down and drying off. Pulleys and bearings are harder to maintain - so a quick stop+shoot becomes a stop+check+clean+shoot. Even running through light woods or long grass can get twigs and fibres stuck in the end of the string, which would render a compound temporarily useless till cleaned (or risk breakage) - while a standard bow would simply work and get cleaned later.

Comment: @Separatrix The 400 yard number refers to where the arrows fell on the ground. Plus, it's made up. English longbows shot far but not that far. 70 m is the distance to archery targets today. Archers today aren't even remotely strong enough to pull one of the super strong English longbows with great range. Obviously, being able to deliver a headshot at 70 m and hoping to hit anyone in a large group of people a few hundred yards away, are quite different goals. No one who knows anything about archery would argue that an English longbow is more precise than a modern compound bow.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that compound bows _must_ have higher strength and hence require stronger materials for bow and arrow, and wear faster. If you're content with the strength of a certain longbow, you could make a compound bow with the same strength too.

Comment: It's implied by some of your points, but you might explicitly mention price

Comment: Range: see https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8022/how-far-could-an-english-war-bow-shoot  Firing rate: some friends of mine used to bow hunt together, one with a compound bow, and the other with a primitive longbow (he was into primitive survival as a hobby). The friend with the longbow would wait until the compound bow was being aimed, then raise pull, aim and shoot before the (already aiming) compound bow could get the shot off. It came down to how you use the arms differently with the two kinds of bows.

Comment: @pojo-guy, that was a great link.  Thanks!  They also pointed out arrow weight.  I remember that some arrows were broadheads for leather/flesh penetration, others were these bulky pointed steel blocks for full armor penetration.  That increased weight would seriously shorten the range, so the bow is only part of the equation.

Comment: Add to your cons for self-bows: many otherwise very suitable materials perform well in a limited rage of conditions. For instance English yew loses considerable strength in hot weather. Though an author may chose to ignore this by simply positing a material without this problem.

Comment: This is similar to why people still use AK-47's despite there being more accurate and lighter rifles on the market. It's heavily standardized, somewhat cheap to manufacture, and it (usually) keeps shooting with only minimal maintenance.

Comment: Though it may weigh more, I do not believe that an unstrung longbow is nearly as bulky as a compound bow.  In fact, I would list the awkwardness of carrying compound bows as one of their tactical disadvantages.

Comment: @pojo-guy I do not know which is faster, but if the compound bow is _already aiming_ then the anecdotal situation you shared is not because of the bow. One of the advantages is the ease of being able to maintain the aiming position, so that you can aim longer without tiring your arms. Still, if already aiming all the compound-bow-user needed to do was, literally, just *let go*. A longbow cannot knock, draw, aim, fire, all faster than a compound bow user can just _let go_. This is coming from the long bow camp: I don't know if I do better or worse with it, but I prefer my long bows.

Comment: The longbow user did not hold the draw - the shots were away (and on target) as soon as the bow was drawn, much to the disgust of my compound bow friend.

Answer (score 55):

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_bow

> Warranties for compound bows do not cover "dry loosing", and it's not
>   unusual for numerous parts, especially the limbs and riser, to be
>   damaged or destroyed after even a single dry loosing. If a string or
>   cable breaks when the bow has been drawn this will have a similar
>   damaging effect on the limbs.

If a string breaks on your longbow you can string it back up in seconds, with the several dry strings you carry.  No doubt archers in wars over the millennia with non-technologically advanced bows did this all the time.   If you break a string in similar circumstances on a compound bow you will be very lucky to be able to repair it in the field.  At best a hunting trip cut short.  At worst you will shortly be parrying sword strokes with your worthless bow.  The broken string and destroyed bow is one example - compound bows are full of other fiddly parts like (several) pulley wheels with ballbearings which can get grit lodged in them and render the bow useless.  Longbows are much simpler and more robust.

Comment: I used to shoot Recurves in the state team where I am (West Aus), and just wanted to add to the quote there.. "If a string or cable breaks when the bow has been drawn this will have a similar damaging effect on the limbs." - Having had compound bows break while shooting, I can confirm that they also have a damaging effect on your limbs. When a carbon bow arm explodes it tends to fill your arm with all sorts of debris, and removes some skin along with it.

Comment: @AaronLavers - that could be the core of a very useful answer. If I were a member of a culture that didn't understand science the way we do now, I'd certainly see a bow that occasionally explodes as a serious indicator that the powers that be do **not** approve of those types of bows.

Comment: @Miller86 And if I were a general in a culture that understood battle tactics, I'd see a bow that explodes as something that fights against me, not for me.

Comment: Dry loosing is just as bad for long bows as it is for compounds and can result in a broken bow.  It's also something of a moot point - one of the first lessons any archer learns is, "never dry-loose this."

Comment: @Will You should check further into the dry firing thing. I seem to recall that "dry firing is very bad" is a (hotly debated, for sure) myth. The Wikipedia "destroyed even after a single dry loosing" quote I would completely disbelieve unless evidence were provided; that sounds like a mighty tall tail. At least, blaming it on the dry firing; if the bow was already junk and about to break on the first use, then of course that is a separate matter, but is in no way the fault of "a single dry loosing".

Comment: @Aaron I am no expert but have certainly heard this before about compound bows.  Enter youtube.  I just watched 3 videos showing people snapping strings dry firing their compound bows (all accidents); there are more.  No exploding bow limbs yet; if you find one pls link it up.

Comment: @Will I likewise am not an expert on this, so I will not assert that my previous comment must be true. I am very skeptical snapping strings are due to the dry firing. I wonder (but doubt) if there are statistics about bow-string-breaks, both from dry-firing and from normal firing. I assume people have strings break also while normal-firing. I have never had a string break on my (long) bows, dry or otherwise, so I have only my intuition to go on. I suspect it's like "there's more (insert: crime, birth, freaks, etc.) on a full moon" You notice because you watch more then. But I've no evidence :(

Comment: Yeah @Will I remember having a guy standing on the line next to me misfire and have the string break/arm snap on him. The bow folded in like an alligator on his arm, and really injured him quite badly. I've never had a recurve let go in such spectacular fashion.

While I've never *seen* a bow snap from a *single* dry-fire, it is etched into you from your very first lessons that you never dry fire it... The bow will *eventually* break - which is what the wikipedia article should really say.

Answer (score 14):

The most obvious reason is the ease of manufacture. With the right wood and a knife, you can whittle a bow. Building a compound bow requires metal working tools.

If a community has limited resources, it may not have the tools to build a compound bow.

If a community had the tools to build a compound bow, they would build crossbows instead. They are easier to use and don't require the training and practice of a bow to be proficient.

The most obvious tactical reasons to use a bow over a gun is that a bow is mostly silent and you have a chance to recover and reuse your arrows. If push came to shove, you could even make your own crude arrows if you ran out.

Comment: Even if the OP meant to say *composite* bows rather than compound bows (composite bows have been around for thousands of years and provided many of the attributes of a modern composite bow in terms of size, draw and poser) the answer is still valid. Complex manufacturing techniques, access to special materials and special maintenance required to keep the bow in top condition make compound *or* composite bows rarer and more expensive than a traditional long or short bow.

Answer (score 3):

You said so yourself: They have limited resources. Even though compound bows are not thought for warfare, but rather for competition or, at best, hunting, they are still far superior to longbows in terms of raw power. However, they are not only harder to manufacture: they're more expensive too. If you're already making a compound bow, you're short from a gun almost just by the powder, and it isn't really justifiable over even a crossbow  - which is much more low-cost in terms of maintenance and can be used with much less training - either. 
A longbow is a logical choice only if you need something that balances fire-power and resource usage.

Comment: Well, you could alternatively use a recurve bow... its less unwieldy, but has other weaknesses.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually going to look at three basic possible kinds of bow, longbows, composites (made from laminated layers of materials with different compressive properties), and compounds made from modern composite materials like carbon fibre or Fiberglas.

Rate and cost of manufacture, as people have mentioned composite or compound  bows are expensive and time consuming to make, if you leave a composite bow to cure by itself, rather than using an oven to force-dry the glues, then it takes years to be usable. Modern compounds just can't *be* manufactured below a certain limit you can't make the material let alone the finished object.

Hot climate, in a dry climate old-school bone/horn, wood, and sinew composite bows can last a lifetime, they usually don't but they can, but they tend to de-laminate when exposed to damp air for extended periods, compounds are the opposite, the sun is NOT your friend if you have a modern compound bow the resins and artificial fibres they are constructed from degrade when exposed to UV. Longbows don't suffer from either of these issues, they're a good all weather weapon.

Ease of use and efficiency of fire, compound and composite bows are only superior for horse archery; you need more room to fire either one in an infantry formation than with Longbows, not a lot more with composites (quite a bit more for compounds) but when it comes to stopping a charge with an arrow storm density and rate of fire are key. Composite and compound bows require a different, longer, draw to generate the same power so rate of fire is marginally reduced. They also both have less "snap" so per pound of draw so a released arrow goes slightly slower, shorter range, less stopping power.

Other issues; compounds and composites are easier to draw at a given draw weight for an untrained archer. Compound bows allow you to "hold the draw" while you aim making them more accurate at the cost of firing rate. Both of these make the weapons easier to use than a longbow but don't necessarily improve combat performance, you don't need "pip the ace" accuracy against massed targets for example.

Comment: With the same draw weight, a compound bow will fire an arrow at a much higher velocity than a longbow will.  This results in a significant advantage in range, accuracy and penetration.


If you equalize the release velocity, the compound bow will require significantly less energy to use.   This will reduce fatigue and allow your troops to sustain a higher rate of fire over a long engagement.


Compound bows are also much smaller and have a shorter draw length.  They would actually be easier to use in a more tightly packed formation than a longbow.